# Join function for OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I have two tables, by joining that 2 tables i need to take distinct count of one particular column from OrientDB. Since joins donot support in OrientDB. Please suggest me in orient db how join works and please suggest me also how to use edges for join in orientdb.

Comment: Hey and welcome. Can you share your code and what you have already tried yourself?

Comment: I have gone through official website of OrientDB and i am unable to find anything on the same. Can you please advice.